# Which keys do I need for CNContactFormatter?

Tags: formatting, ios9, cncontact, cncontactformatter, cncontactstore

I'm trying to format a contact's name using the new `CNContactFormatter`. It looks like, I didn't fetch all needed name properties of the contact.

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'CNPropertyNotFetchedException', reason: 'A property was not requested when contact was fetched.'
```

Does anyone know which ones are required? I tried fetching the following amongst a few others with no luck:

```
        CNContactNamePrefixKey,
        CNContactGivenNameKey,
        CNContactFamilyNameKey,
        CNContactMiddleNameKey, 
        CNContactPreviousFamilyNameKey,
        CNContactNameSuffixKey,
        CNContactNicknameKey,
        CNContactPhoneticGivenNameKey,
        CNContactPhoneticMiddleNameKey,
        CNContactPhoneticFamilyNameKey,
        CNContactOrganizationNameKey,
        CNContactDepartmentNameKey,
        CNContactJobTitleKey,
```

Neither the [CNContactFomatter Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Contacts/Reference/CNContactFormatter_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/CNContactFormatter) nor the [fetching method's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Contacts/Reference/CNContactStore_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CNContactStore/unifiedContactsMatchingPredicate:keysToFetch:error:) give any clue.

Thanks!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I found this in the WWDC Session 223 (starting at slide 74) and this worked for me when I was having the same problem.  Use CNContactFormatter.descriptorForRequiredKeysForStyle... in the contact selection call.  Example:

```
let contactStore = CNContactStore()
let predicate = CNContact.predicateForContactsMatchingName("John")
let foundContacts = try contactStore.unifiedContactsMatchingPredicate(predicate, keysToFetch: [CNContactFormatter.descriptorForRequiredKeysForStyle(.FullName)]
for contact in foundContacts {
            print(CNContactFormatter.stringFromContact(contact, style: .FullName))
}
```

Comment: Oh man, thank you! That works like a charm, even combined with some additional fields.

Comment: WOW. Deep cut. Thank you so much for sharing this solution!

Answer (score 2):

```
class func descriptorForRequiredKeys()
```

*Use to fetch all contact keys required to create vCard data from a contact.*

https://developer.apple.com/reference/contacts/cncontactvcardserialization

Example:

```
let containerResults =  try contactStore.unifiedContacts(matching: fetchPredicate, keysToFetch:[CNContactVCardSerialization.descriptorForRequiredKeys()])
```

Comment: Isn't that different from https://developer.apple.com/documentation/contacts/cncontactformatter/1397746-descriptorforrequiredkeys ?